# IDbDataAdapter Adapter() => new SqlDataAdapter(); throwing exception

Tags: c#

```
public IDbDataAdapter Adapter() => new SqlDataAdapter();
```

Why does this statement throws the following errors:

- on `=>` it says `; expected`
- and on `SqlDataAdapter();` its says `Method must have a return type`

Comment: Sounds like you're using an older version of C# (earlier than C# 6) - one that doesn't yet understand the "Expression-bodied function members" syntax

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ""Expression-bodied function members" notation is a new feature in C# 6.0 - maybe you're using an older version of C#?

So instead of

```
public IDbDataAdapter Adapter() => new SqlDataAdapter();
```

can you try to use:

```
public IDbDataAdapter Adapter()
{ 
    return new SqlDataAdapter(); 
}
```

Does this work?